# Exportar resultado de un select a un archivo de texto

Tags: sql, tsql

Tengo un SELECT en SQL Server y lo quiero exportar a un archivo de texto (resultado.txt), veo que se puede hacer con algún lenguaje de programación, pero quiero hacerlo con TSQL. 
¿Si es eso posible?

Comment: Si, es posible hacerlo con TSQL.

Comment: Hola! mira por favor [ask]. Debes decir que has investigado/probado hasta ahora. Y como esta hecha tu pregunta, la respuesta es si.

Comment: @gbianchi , ok ya revise y tienes razón estuvo mal formulada mi pregunta, ofrezco disculpas, pero solo hago la aclaración que ya había investigado pero aún tenía dudas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al menos para SQL Server debes hacer:

Debe primero ejecutar estas consultas

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure ‘show advanced options’, 1
RECONFIGURE
EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure ‘xp_cmdshell’, 1
RECONFIGURE
```

esto es para asegurarnos que el xp_cmdshell esta habilitado

Com paso 2 debes usar este comando

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell ‘bcp “SELECT * FROM sysfiles” queryout “C:\bcptest.txt” -T -c -t,’
```

aqui tenemos que le pasamos el query tal cual lo necesitamos, y le pasamos la ruta donde queremos que cree el archivo de texto (la ruta deber ser local)

Los parámetros que se están utilizando son:

**Queryout** – es la que permite espeficar el query con el que se trabajara

**File name** – donde se insertara el resultado (debe ser la ruta completa)

**-T**, que especifica que la utilidad bcp se conectara a SQL Server con una conección segura, se pude usar -P (contraseña) y -U (usuario)

**-c**, especifica el tipo de caracteres que se usara para cada campo

**-t**, permite especificar el delimitador de campo, el caracter que se especifique despues del -t sera el que separe cada campo

**-S**, se pude usar para espeficar el nombre del servidor. Si se tiene una Instancia nombrada, sera forzoso usar este parámetro. Algo así como,

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell ‘bcp “select name, type_desc, create_date from sys.objects” queryout “C:\bcptest2.txt” -T -SDEVELOP\DEV1 -c -t,’
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @jose!!! me quedo mucho mas claro, ahora solo tengo que revisar algunos puntos sobre seguridad de donde guardar el archivo.

Comment: Mas alla que la respuesta sea correcta, se trata de no contestar esta clase de preguntas tan amplias que no demuestran siquiera una minima investigacion.