# Generar archivo.txt desde una consulta

Tags: sql, sql-server

buenos dias.
necesito una ayuda, tengo la siguiente consulta que les mostrare, pero el tema es mostrar los datos que me muestra en un archivo.txt,espero me puedan ayudar y de ante todos gracias totales.

```
select convert(varchar(8), contd.FechaContable, 112)as Periodo, cta.Cuenta, 
(case cta.cuenta
            when '10166' then '99'  --C.Chica Boutique Chanel
            when '10167' then '99'  --C.Chica Swarovski Jockey Plaza
            when '10168' then '99'  --C.Chica Vulcano
            when '10169' then '99'  --C.Chica Swarovski RP Salaverry
            when '10170' then '99'  --C.Chica Real Plaza Salaverry
            when '10171' then '99'  --C.Chica Cross Larcomar
            when '10172' then '99'  --C.Chica Secretaria de Gerencia
            else '_'
            end) as Codigo,
            CTADINERO.NumeroCta, 
            (Case CTADINERO.MONEDA
                     WHEN 'Soles' then 'PEN'
                    WHEN 'Dolares' then 'USD'
                    WHEN 'Euros' then 'EUR'
                    ELSE 'PEN' END) as Moneda, 
             sum(case when isnull(contd.debe,0) > isnull(contd.haber,0)  
 then (isnull(contd.debe,0) - isnull(contd.haber,0)) else 0 end) 
 SaldoDeudor,
           sum(case when isnull(contd.haber,0) > isnull(contd.debe,0)  then 
 (isnull(contd.haber,0) - isnull(contd.debe,0)) else 0 end) SaldoAcreedor,
           Estado=1
             from cta (nolock)
             left outer join contd (nolock) on cta.cuenta = contd.cuenta 
             left outer join CTADINERO (nolock) on CTADINERO.cuenta = 
contd.cuenta

             WHERE contd.cuenta  = '10415'
             and contd.ejercicio = '2018'
             group by contd.FechaContable,contd.ID, cta.cuenta, 
CTADINERO.NUMEROCTA, CTADINERO.MONEDA
```

[image: Quiero mostrar estos registro en archivo.txt]

Comment: Mira esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/121019/exportar-resultado-de-un-select-a-un-archivo-de-texto

Answer (score 1):

Para extraer la información de sql a un archivo de texto, tienes que usar el comando xp_cmdshell, para poderlo usar debes hacer primero:
Activar el comando cp_cmdshell con el siguiente script:
- EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1

Posteriormente 
- Ejecutar tu consulta haciendo uso del comando sp_cmdshell, como ejemplo te muestro:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT [nit],[EMPRESA], 
[FACTURACION_REAL],REPLACE(REPLACE([DOMICILIO_FACTURACION],CHAR(10),'' 
''),CHAR(13),'' '') ,[FECHA_CREACION_CLIENTE] FROM 
dbIntegradorCrm.dbo.INTEGRADOR_CRM_SVA" queryout 
"E:\Integrador\archivo.csv" -T -Sservidor -c -t,'
```

Lo que yo haría en tu caso para facilitar el código es crear una vista e invocar la vista desde el ejemplo de la consulta, quedando así:
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT Criterios FROM Vista WHERE Condiciones" queryout "E:\Integrador\archivo.csv" -T -Sservidor -c -t,'

Estoy seguro que con el script anterior lograras extraer la información al archivo que necesitas.